# How to create unique footers for Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I've been trying to create a footer at the end of a Telerik Grid, but have been unable to get a unique value stored (likely due to the foreach loop approach in the grid's implementation).

I would like to be able to put the `double` values from the `Daytotals` array in as the footer for the following columns, but the end result is the value from `Daytotal[6]` written to the footer for all columns.

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

View Code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Projectid).Title("Project").Width(80);
        //Days
        foreach(WorkoutByDay tc in Model)
        {
            DateTime currentDate = startdate.Value.AddDays(count).Date;
            columns.Bound(o => o.HoursDay)
                .Template(
                    @<text>
                        @Html.Raw((@item.WorkoutDate.Value.Date == currentDate) ? item.HoursDay.ToString() : "-")
                    </text>)
                .Title(startdate.Value.AddDays(count).ToShortDateString())
                .Format("{0}")
                .FooterTemplate( @<text> @Html.Raw(Daytotals[count].ToString()) </text>)
                .Width(55);
            count++;
        }
        columns.Bound(o => o.HoursDay).Title("Total").Width(45);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Title("").Width(5);
    })
)
```

`

`

Answer (score 0):

First thing that i can think of is that you don't need foreach loop in telerik grid. it effectively means that you will generate your columns n times where n in the count of your model enumeration. if your model is of type IEumerable then grid automatically takes care of looping through the values and generating rows so you should remove foreach loop. Second thing is that if you want to display total (average, count, etc.) in footer you can use telerik's aggregates. They are available both for server and ajax binding. you can find demos at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregatesserverside?theme=vista